# Creating inner query in hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate

I have to create this type of query in criteria query in hibernate

```
SELECT *
        FROM
        ${hibernate.default_schema}.VW_GEMS_CUST_TRNG_RPT CUSTOMER,
        (SELECT * FROM ${hibernate.default_schema}.VW_GEMS_VENUE WHERE ORG_NAME =?)
        VENUE
        WHERE
        CUSTOMER.PRIMARY_VENUE_ROW_ID = VENUE.VENUE_ROW_ID(+)
        AND CUSTOMER.ORG_NAME =?
        AND CUSTOMER.CONTACT_ID =?
        ORDER BY CUSTOMER.EVNT_START_DT DESC
```

How do I do this?

Comment: subselects in the FROM clause are not possible with criteria api

Answer (score 0):

Sub-selects in the ROM clause cannot be used with the criteria API.
But you can rewrite the query without the sub-select.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ${hibernate.default_schema}.VW_GEMS_CUST_TRNG_RPT CUSTOMER
inner join ${hibernate.default_schema}.VW_GEMS_VENUE VENUE
        on (CUSTOMER.PRIMARY_VENUE_ROW_ID = VENUE.VENUE_ROW_ID(+) 
       and venue.ORG_NAME =?)
WHERE
      CUSTOMER.ORG_NAME =?
      AND CUSTOMER.CONTACT_ID =?
ORDER BY CUSTOMER.EVNT_START_DT DESC
```